# Haskell Formatting I/O Error

Tags: haskell, input, formatting, output

I'm having a problem figuring out why I am getting a parse error when compiling code. I've tried indenting using tabs and spaces yet no success. Maybe I just need another set of eyes on the code, any help would be greatly appreciated!

The error seems to be coming from this line:

> putStrLn "\nSelected option: "

```
main :: IO()
main = do contents <- readFile "films.txt";
          let database = (read contents :: [Film])
          putStrLn "Please enter your name:";
          name <- getLine;
          putStrLn ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!");
          menu database
          where menu newDb = do putStrLn "\nWhat would you like to do?";
                                putStrLn "1 -> Add a film";
                                putStrLn "2 -> Display all films";
                                putStrLn "3 -> Display all films by director's name";
                                putStrLn "4 -> Display the films of an average website rating";
                                putStrLn "5 -> Display the average rating of the films of a particular actor";
                                putStrLn "6 -> Show the films you have rated, with the rating";
                                putStrLn "7 -> Rate or ReRate a film";
                                putStrLn "8 -> Display films released during or after a year, sorted in descending order of rating";
                                putStrLn "9 -> Exit & Save";
                                putStrLn "\nSelected option: "
                                option <- getLine
                                case option of 
                                     "1" -> do putStr "Name of Film: "
                                             title <- getLine
                                             putStr "Name of the Director: "
                                             director <- getLine
                                             putStr "Year the film was released: "
                                             year <- getLine
                                             putStrLn (map formatFilmOutput $ addFilm title director (read year) [] newDb)
                                     "2" -> do putStrLn (displayAllFilm newDb) >> menu newDb
```

Comment: I get a different error when I try, it's on the line `title <- getLine`.  Do you happen to use tabs in your editor?  Haskell allows mixing them, but tabs aren't necessarily parsed as you see it in your editor.

Comment: Yes ive tabbed everything, i may have used spaces on a few lines. Just tested it again, when commented out everything seems fine but when added the parse error reappears.

Comment: Find the setting in your editor that replaces tabs with spaces.  I promise that it'll make things easier.  It's like Python, tabs can be used, but people end up having parse errors.

Comment: Cheers i will give it a go, but starting to see other problems that may arise with my project so i will have to come back to this

Comment: Try to put a space befoer the first while and see if that works ...

Comment: Seemed to have fixed it. God dam spaces and tabs!

Comment: Also try to be consistent with your use of semicolons e.g.  `putStrLn "9 -> Exit & Save";`  vs  `putStrLn "\nSelected option: "`  ...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I've tried indenting using tabs and spaces yet no success." - there's your problem.  Find an editor that will, upon saving a file, replace tabs with spaces; or set your tab stops to be 8 characters.

The Haskell Report, section 10.3:

```
Tab stops are 8 characters apart.
http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3
```